# Websocket client in android shell

Tags: android, websocket, sh, adb

I faced with problem. Need to send request via websocket from android command line shell, but I don't know how.
I just need to send request to localhost:port and get response body

I tried to use nc, but something was wrong

Comment: Android adb shell only have a very small set of commands available. Commands for performing websocket requestsikn are as far as I know not included. So you have to first get tpa binary you can use like curl. Install Terms from F-Droid (not Play Store that one is outdated) and install cruel or a similar command. Then you can use it from within Termux of try to copy the binary plus libraries to a place where you can access it from adb shell.

Comment: @robert i need do that only with adb shell, without termux

Comment: Then use a second phone, install Termux there and install e.g. curl. Tar curl and the libraries and extract it via adb and on the target phone do the same in reverse. Extract curl and libraries to `/data/local` or `/data/local/tmp` what ever works.

Comment: Glad you're getting help, but StackOverflow is dedicated to helping with `if/then/else` programming code (and tools) problems. Also, you need more detail about what steps failed, rather than "something was wrong" (-;! . Your Q seems to be about using Android software. Did you know there is [android.se] that should be  helpul for these issues? Voting to close as not about programming. (Sorry), but Good luck.